# Laravel: Redirecting to same route after filtering data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have an index page where I list all the data that I have and there is also a simple filtering form that makes a `POST` request to its given route

```
@section('content')

    <h4>Maçlar</h4>

    <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="{{ route('games.filter') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group mb-2">
            <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="season-select" name="season">
                <option value="0">Tüm Sezonlar</option>
                @foreach ($seasons as $season)
                    <option value="{{$season->id}}" {{old('season') == $season->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$season->season}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
            <label for="week-select" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="week-select" name="week">
                <option value="0">Tüm Haftalar</option>
                @foreach ($weeks as $week)
                    <option value="{{$week->id}}" {{old('week') == $week->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$week->week}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Filtrele</button>
    </form>

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Sezon</th>
            <th scope="col">Hafta</th>
            <th scope="col">Ev Sahibi Takım</th>
            <th scope="col">Misafir Takım</th>
            <th scope="col">Tarih ve Saat</th>
            <th scope="col">Yer</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach ($games as $game)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$game->season->season}}</td>
                <td>{{$game->week->week}}</td>
                <td>{{@$game->homeTeam->name}}</td>
                <td>{{@$game->awayTeam->name}}</td>
                <td>{{@$game->game_date_time}}</td>
                <td>{{@$game->place}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

@endsection
```

And in the controller my index method is as below

```
public function index()
{
     $seasons = Season::all();
     $weeks = Week::all();
     $games = Game::with('season', 'week', 'homeTeam', 'awayTeam')->get();

     return view('game.index')->with(compact('games', 'seasons', 'weeks'));
}
```

And there is also my filter method which performs `POST` request and passes filtered data to same view as index uses.

```
public function filter(Request $request)
{
     $seasons = Season::all();
     $weeks = Week::all();

     $games = Game::with('season', 'week', 'homeTeam', 'awayTeam')
                ->when(request('season') != 0, function ($q) {
                    return $q->where('season_id', request('season'));
                })->when(request('week') != 0, function ($q) {
                    return $q->where('week_id', request('week'));
                })
                ->get();

     return view('game.index')->with(compact('games', 'seasons', 'weeks'));
}
```

What I want to learn is, what is the best way of implementing such a case ? Is it possible to redirect back to same index route after performing `POST` request for filtering ? And `old` method does not work in the blade template so I can not display old form data after the request. What can be the problem with it ? Lastly, how can I remove these duplicate rows in the index and filter methods.

```
$seasons = Season::all();
$weeks = Week::all();
```

Any help would be appreciated. PS: I do not want to use Ajax, Vue.js etc. I want to do it with Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use filter in index method. No need to create another method for filter.

change in view.

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="{{ route('games.index') }}"> // form redirect to index method
```

change in index method.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
     $seasons = Season::all();
     $weeks = Week::all();

     if($request->has('season') && $request->has('week') ){ // check filter value is passed or not
      $games = Game::with('season', 'week', 'homeTeam', 'awayTeam')
                ->when(request('season') != 0, function ($q) {
                    return $q->where('season_id', request('season'));
                })->when(request('week') != 0, function ($q) {
                    return $q->where('week_id', request('week'));
                })
                ->get();
     }
     else{
        $games = Game::with('season', 'week', 'homeTeam', 'awayTeam')->get();
     }

     return view('game.index')->with(compact('games', 'seasons', 'weeks'));
}
```

Comment: I am using a resource controller and I think games.index POST route used by store function already. Sorry, I did not mention this in my question.

Comment: I mean there is route as below so I can not use only games since it is already used by store. Or am I wrong ?
POST| games | games.store

Comment: Also games.idex is a get method but form's method is POST. How is it gonna work ?

Comment: mostly search form is get and it is also fast . so you can use games.index as GET